# assigning a key in object javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering how can do something like this:

Output I am looking for:

```
{ item_id0 : 123, quantity0: 99 , item_id1 : 124, quantity1: 50 }
```

My sample code but not working:

```
var data = {};
angular.forEach(vm.fields, function(value, key){
    data = {
        item_id[key] : vm.selectedItem[key].id,
        quantity[key] : vm.quantity[key]
    }
})
console.log(data);
```

Comment: forEach((elem, id, array) => {
 // code
})

what is it vm.fields?

Comment: Aside from it being a Bad Idea (you should have something more like `[{id:123,quantity:99}, {id:124,quantity:50}]`) you could probably be better off just doing `data['item_id'+key] = vm.selectedItem[key].id;`

Comment: Is the formatting important? You really want the fields to be named item_id0, quantity0, item_id1, quantity1 and so on?

Comment: @Artem, it is an object that needed for my input fields.

@NiettheDarkAbsol, thank you for that. But when I passing it to parameter it does return null. `$http.post('server/add-transaction.php', data).then(function(res){
                        console.log(res);
                  })`

@Schorsch, formating is not really important but I think I need it to pass in my php insert query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following to obtain data in the format that you need, following code accesses property by its name string and gives it some value.

```
  $scope.property = {};

  for(i = 0; i< 10;i++){
    $scope.property['item_id'+ i] = i;
    $scope.property['quantity' + i] = i+20;
  }
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/J7zabZ8sjqc6Rwm9ZfTT?p=preview)